# How to use pathauto and transliteration modules together?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

it might be obvious, but i couldn't find out how.

Comment: i have just read the project page in drupal.org  
it seems only pathauto 2.x uses transliteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pathauto 2.x will use the Transliteration module.

Answer (score 1):

There's a checkbox at `admin/build/path/pathauto` called *Transliterate prior to creating alias*. If it's not there, check to see if you have latest version.

Comment: but it doesn't use the transliteration module. the transliteration module is meant for files only, afaik.

Comment: It will use the transliteration module, if you enable it.

Transliteration is about converting special chars, which is also can be used for urls, not just file names.